# Should TypeScript warn when a conditional always evaluates to false?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

```
const someString = 'a';

if (!someString) {
  window.alert('hi');
}
```

In the code above, `window.alert` will never get called since `!'a'` always evaluates to `false`. Since TypeScript knows the type of `someString` is `'a'`, it has the necessary knowledge to alert the developer that `window.alert` is dead code.

I have TypeScript 2.9.1 installed along with TSLint. Should either of these tools warn in this scenario? If not, is there a bug open in their GitHub repositories?

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9041

Comment: @Corey, why does Typescript need to check runtime value `'a'`, shouldn't the type be the only concern?

Comment: @ABOS Not entirely sure if this answers your question, but the type of `someString` in the code above is `'a'` which is a subtype (I think?) of `string` https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/literal-types.html

Comment: what if const something = func(someConstants....), does TS need to evaluate it at compiling time?

Comment: @ABOS I don't quite understand what you're asking and also not sure how that's relevant to my question. Can you explain?

Comment: @CoreyFarwell, what I am trying to say is that typescript should not care about evaluating the expression to optimize code, IMHO, it is some other tools like clojurescript's job.

Comment: @ABOS So far I've only spoken about type checking and linting – I haven't mentioned anything about evaluating expressions or optimizing code

Comment: @CoreyFarwell, but what you have asked is essentially optimizing code based on expression...It is already beyond TS's simple task of type checking

Comment: Linting and type checking is different from optimizing and expression evaluation. We're going in circles here, not sure how I can make this clearer...